# Consequence of NP=coNP to some hierarchy problems

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If $NP=coNP$ does it hold that $P/Poly=PH/Poly$ and/or $NP\subseteq P/Poly$ and/or $VNP=VP$?

What can we legitimately say if $NP=coNP$?

Comment: Probably nothing of the sort you suggest.

Comment: The reason I asked was isnt it true $NP=coNP\implies PH=NP$?

Comment: Yes, this one is true, but we don't know any of the implications you suggest.

Comment: In a sense $NP=coNP$ says much stronger than $VP=VNP$  though right?

Comment: No, the two are connected only by notation and analogy.

Comment: Do you know consequential information on  cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32568/consequences-of-vp-vnp-on-randomness?

Comment: Josh known the area better than me, so I defer to him.

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/consequences-of-np-conp-and-p-ne-np

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no such implications are known.

Comment: For instance, for all we know FACTORING has no polynomial-time algorithm, so NP != P, but NP = coNP.  (Background: FACTORING is in NP intersect coNP.)  I don't know of any result that contradicts this possibility.